# Add a caption when sending content to Facebook Messenger

Tags: android, facebook, messenger

Do you guys please know how to add extra text to Messenger Utils?
this is the code i have in my application, when i try to use the normal intent to share, the reply button doesn't show.

```
  ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
  ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(bmpUri, "image/*")
  .build();
  MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(this,1,
  shareToMessengerParams);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook developper sent me a message telling me that it's impossible to write caption in facebook, it's against facebook policy